# react-native-image-modal open image modal programmatically when clicking the button then toggle the modal

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native

I'm using react-native-image-modal package to display the image in modal but its not opening onclick button I need to open modal when button is clicked.

current code:

```js
import ImageModal from 'react-native-image-modal';

<TouchableOpacity
                            activeOpacity={0.6}
                            onPress={() => {
                             
                            }}
                            style={{
                              borderWidth: 1,
                              borderColor: '#FF9898',
                              borderRadius: 50,
                              position: 'absolute',
                            }}>
                            <Text className="text-warning font-[500] text-[11px] py-[3px] px-2">
                              See Image
                            </Text>
                          </TouchableOpacity>
          <View>
            <ImageModal
              ref={modalBtn}
              resizeMode="contain"
              modalRef={imageModal}
              imageBackgroundColor="#000000"
              style={{
                width: 400,
                height: 400,
              }}
              source={{
                uri: 'https://res.cloudinary.com/duldhdjsj/image/upload/v17042/litnldacr4.jpg',
              }}
            />
          </View>
```

I want onclick see image button , I need the modal to be shown

Comment: This library is currently not supporting open modal programmatically, see the [issue in github](https://github.com/dev-yakuza/react-native-image-modal/issues/53).

Comment: could you try modalBtn.current.open();

Answer (score 0):

The modal in this library cannot be open with an onPress, the open button is on the image itself

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Can you just wrap the `<ImageModal>` component in a conditional boolean state? Such as:

```
const [showingModal, setShowingModal] = useState(false);
```

Your button handler can call `setShowingModal(true);`

In your render function, you can then wrap the rendering of `ImageModal` in a conditional:

```
{showingModal && <ImageModal...
```